# dynamic_form gem causes console not to load. Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I installed 'dynamic_form' gem in my rails 4.1.4 app.  When I tried to run console (bundle exec rails console) I get the error below:

```
$ bundle exec rails console
Could not find dynamic_form-1.1.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But when I run server (bundle exec rails server) seems to work just fine.
Anyone else encountered this issue? thanks!

Comment: also already checked my Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.  dynamic_form is there. thanks!

Comment: please check the dynamic_form gem is installed or not using gem list dynamic_form, it will show you list of dynamic_form gem and its version, if not installed with 1.1.4 try with gem install dynamic_form  -v '1.1.4' from your terminal

Comment: thanks for the reply @DeeptiKakade.  I already did that.  I got 'dynamic_form (1.1.4)'.  Also tried installing manually via gem install with the version and still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [this gem](https://github.com/joelmoss/dynamic_form), it looks to be significantly outdated. I doubt it has official Rails 4 support. Someone actually submitted an issue asking if Rails 4 support will be added.

Consider using another form gem - there are plenty.